# How to get signup user id in another controller in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable

user.rb

```
has_one :company
```

My requirement is that when user sign up page is redirect to new `company` form. How can I get sign up user id there?

Is it possible?

Comment: Use `current_user.id`

Comment: After signup device login user if email not conformable so you can use current_user.id

Comment: Can I use current_user.id after signup?

Comment: Yes, normally user logged in after signup by devise gem

Answer (score 0):

After signup devise gem login signup user if email not conformable so you can use current_user.id
if for any reason you are not logged in after signup then 
login user and use current_user.id there

Put this code in application_controller.rb

```
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   sign_in resource
   #your path #company path in your case

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Devise provides an helper method "current_user", which store the information of sign_up user

you can use  current_user.id